Prove that $M\in{L}\cup\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $a_n\to L,b_n\to M$ and $\{b_n\}\subseteq \{L\}\cup\{a_n\}$
Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence such that for every $n$ we have $b_n\in\{L\}\cup\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. We want to prove that if $(b_n)$ converges to $M$ then $M\in\{L\}\cup\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now, I can see (but can't manage to rigorously prove) that either $(b_n)$ is eventually constant with constant $L$ or $a_n$ for some $n$, or is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and therefore $L=M$.
How can we make this idea rigorous?

If there are infinitely many $b_n$ equal to $L$, we're done. Then let us assume there are only finitely many $n'$s for which $b_n=L$. Hence $\exists n_0$ s.t for every $n\geq n_0$, $b_n\in\{a_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. WLOG, let us assume $n_0=1$ (it would be easier). For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $k(n)$ be the index satisfying $b_n=a_{k(n)}$. There are two options: if $k(n)$ takes finitely many different values, then $b_n$ must be constant from a certain point - this is because if, wlog, $k(i)$ and $k(j)$ appear infinitely many times (and $a_{k(i)}$, $a_{k(j)}$ are different), take two subsequences of $b_n$ - one is constant $a_{k(i)}$ and the other is constant $a_{k(j)}$, this would contradict the fact that $b_n$ converges. Therefore, $b_n$ is constant $a_{k(i)}$ for some $i$, and $M=a_{k(i)}$.
The other option is that $k:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ has an infinite image. In this case, take a sequence of natural numbers $n_j$ such that $k(n_j)<k(n_{j+1})$ (convince yourself you can do so). Then $b_{n_j}$ is a subsequence of $b_n$, hence converges to $M$. On the other hand, $a_{k(n_j)}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$, hence converges to $L$, and $M=L$.
